# JS Events help - when changing a style property

Tags: javascript, syntax, dom-events, background-image

I have a code here that i was supposed to make to change a style property, managed to make it work, but had to look up at the proper way to place the ', the " and the + .

```js
    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage="url('" + element.src + "')";
```

I have no issue understanding how structurally this works, my only question resides on why of the extra ', extra " and extra + inside where you call for the element.src.

originally i did something like this, and it obviously didnt work, why did those ('" + and + "') make the code work...

any help is appreciated

cheers

```js
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage="url(' element.src ')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze everything from your first code segment and that should give you a better understanding:

```
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage="url('" + element.src + "')";
```

`document` is a variable

`getElementById` is a function, with the string `'image'` being a parameter for that function.

`style` is a property

`backgroundImage` is a property which must be and must take a string

`"url('"` is a string

`element` is a variable, an object in this case, with `src` being one of its properties.

`"')"` is a string

The `+` signs are used to concatenate the string formed from `"url('"`, element.src and "')". In short you are saying, "make a string from `"url('"`, `element.src` and `"')"` and assign that string to the property `backgroundImage`.

Whereas in this:

```
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage="url(' element.src ')";
```

The browser has no idea that `element.src` is a variable and not part of the string, since you enclosed it int double quotes, signaling that everything between the quotes is a string.

Comment: i totally understand, also i noticed i can avoid this configuration (" url ' " +) and manage to go without having to use the extra ', as such (" url " +).

Answer (score 1):

`element` is a variable outside of a string literal, but inside a string literal it is just the word element.

```js
const element = "Hello!";

const first = "start element end";
const second = "start " + element + " end";

console.log({first,second});
```

Comment: ok, i totally get it now!

i thought it was due to some convention in syntax, instead its the only way to include the element.src, cos otherwise it converts it into string, gotcha!

really appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Inside of CSS, you have to put your URL inside of quotes or apostrophes, so that has to translate to the javascript as well.

When you call the DOM event it will do this:

Original tag:

```
<div src="http://example.com/image.png"></div>
```

after calling the javascript function:

```
<div style="background-image: url('http://example.com/image.png');" src="http://example.com/image.png"></div>
```

and because you need to have some sort of quotation in the URL syntax, you have to use a different kind of quotation, such as the `''` in this case.

For more reference on the background image style, you can go here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background_image.asp

but to completely answer your question, the `+` in there is used to say that you want to add something else there, such as another string or a variable.

More information on that here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp (you have to scroll down a bit to the string operators section).